# strange behavior of lua_getfield

Tags: c++, lua

I have spotted strange behavior with lua_getfield() function. Please look at this code fragment, which should just get a field from table located at the stack top:

```
if(lua_istable(L,-1)){
  lua_getfield(L,-1,"field_name");
  int type = lua_type(L,-1);         // returns LUA_TNIL
  int field_value = lua_tointeger(L,-1); // returns 0

  lua_pop(L,1);

  // and now let's try iterating all table's fields:
  lua_pushnil(L);  // first key
  while(lua_next(L, -2) != 0){
    // uses 'key' (at index -2) and 'value' (at index -1)
    CString key = lua_tostring(L,-2);
    int type = lua_type(L,-1);

    if(key == "field_name"){ // 
      int value = lua_tointeger(L,-1); // returns correct value!!!!  (type == LUA_TNUMBER)
      // ????? what the heck ????
    }

    // removes 'value'; keeps 'key' for next iteration
    lua_pop(L, 1);
  }
```

The question is, why lua_getfield() doesn't work, while lua_next() works perfectly?
I have used lua_getfield() tens of times with no problems and now I'm bumping my head into my keyboard...

reagards
Marcin

Comment: Cannot reproduce the behavior, your code verbatim works fine on my box. Check for typos, etc...

Comment: Problem solved.There was a problem with adjusting the number of results returned by previous call to lua_pcall. What confuses me though, is why lua_next worked correctly when lua_getfield() miserabely failed...

Comment: please make your comment an answer to this question, then accept it since you have identified the underlying issue and solved the problem.

Comment: `if(key == "field_name"){` looks fishy. Are you really intending to compare pointers instead of the contents of the string (i.e. strcmp)?

Comment: @Judge, as key is of CString class, it compares with no problem with const char* (I use this routinely in my day to day work).

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. There was a problem with adjusting the number of results returned by previous call to lua_pcall. What confuses me though, is why lua_next worked correctly when lua_getfield() miserabely failed...